# ViewBag e ViewData Dúvida

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou iniciando a carreira em desenvolvimento, e no projeto aqui da empresa, encontrei uma `ViewData` sendo utilizada, e pelas minhas pesquisas eu não consigo atualizá-la em um `ActionResult` no controller. Acabei testando com uma `ViewBag` também, onde também fui infeliz. Lembrando que o valor destas duas serão atribuídos na renderização da página, correto? (Me corrijam, por favor)

Como eu poderia fazer para recuperar este valores, via `ajax`, até outra questão, pois minhas funções .js estão em um outro arquivo, não localizados dentro do `Index.cshtml`

**Edit 1:** No meu cenário atual, está acontecendo o seguinte:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   // Crio minha ViewData
   ViewData["NomeDaViewData"] = null;
   UpdateViewData(); // aqui onde vou atualizá-la

   return View();
}

private void UpdateViewData()
{
   var dado = _myReposiory.BuscaValor();
   ViewData["NomeDaViewData"] = dado;
}
```

Logo após no meu Index jogo o valor da ViewData em um input hidden, onde consigo trabalhar no meu arquivo .js tranquilamente. Mas vejo que posso melhor esta maneira, só não sei como.

Comment: quando você diz "via ajax", quer dizer que no `javascript` precisa de um valor que foi passado por `ViewData` ou `ViewBag` é isso?

Comment: Voce quer passar o valor do ajax que esta na View para o Controller?

Comment: Isso mesmo @RicardoPontual.

Comment: Gostaria de passar um valor que está no meu Controller para a minha View @RobsonOliveira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os valores da `ViewData`, `ViewBag`ou ainda `TempData` não podem ser acessados no arquivo `javascript`, o que dificulta a utilização posterior numa chamada `Ajax`.

Uma solução é ler no arquivo *.cshtml*, e colocar numa variável javascript, que possa ser acessada depois por seu arquivo, por exemplo:

**arquivo.cshtml**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var valorDaController = '@ViewData["Valor"]';
<script>
```

**outroArquivo.js**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://blablabla.com.br',
   data: {
      valor: valorDaController 
   }, ....
```

Comment: Obrigado cara!! Uma outra solução que o pessoal me indicou aqui, foi colocar o valor dentro de um input hidden, aí consigo acessar de qualquer lugar

Comment: Boa, o importante é saber que você deve fazer isso no *.cshtml*